# Why are the outputs of the md5sum tool and Crypto++'s MD5 different?

Tags: hash, md5

Could you please tell me what is the difference of coreutils' `md5sum` and `sha*sum` tools (`sha1sum`, `sha224sum`, etc.) compared to Crypto++'s digest functions?

I've written a piece of code using Crypto++ hash functions but the result is different from the corresponding Unix tools'.

For example if I write in command line:

```
 echo test123 | md5sum
```

I get:

```
4a251a2ef9bbf4ccc35f97aba2c9cbda
```

but the Crypto++ MD5 function results with:

```
cc03e747a6afbbcbf8be7668acfebee5
```

Similar things happens when I use another digest functions (as mentioned earlier).

Both Unix and Crypto++ manuals says it simply calculates digest, but says nothing about output format.

I can see both have the same length, both seem to be in hexadecimal form (0-f) and moreover when I type the hashes into Google, in both cases it says that it is an MD5 hash of `test123`.

Do you have any ideas about it?

Comment: Try `echo -n test123 | md5sum`. The `echo` command appends a newline unless used with the `-n` flag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `echo` command appends a new line at the end, by default. The `-n` option omits this character. Compare these two executions:

```
> echo -n "test123" | md5sum
cc03e747a6afbbcbf8be7668acfebee5

> echo "test123" | md5sum
4a251a2ef9bbf4ccc35f97aba2c9cbda
```

So the difference between the hash values is simply caused by the new line character.

Comment: indeed, that's the case. So simple, that i feel ashamed of my question ;)

Comment: @crooveck Don't worry — I guess most people have discovered this trap some time...